# How can I randomly select one of three strings?

Tags: vb.net

I have to create a password and I believe that I can do it, however I am stumped at the very beginning. I have 3 strings of characters, I would like to randomly select one of these three strings. Does anybody know how to do it?

```
  Dim sLowerCase As String = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
        Dim sUpperCase As String = "MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ"
        Dim sNumbers As String = "1234567890"
```

So I want to randomly select one of these three strings

Comment: Downvote? Again? It's a legitimate question

Comment: Of course. Your research effort is equal to or less than `0`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to  use ListOf string instead for this. you can code like the following;

```
    Dim listofStrings As New List(Of String) ' Declaration of list of strings
    listofStrings.Add("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm") 'assign values to the list
    listofStrings.Add("MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ")
    listofStrings.Add("1234567890")
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim randomString As String = listofStrings.Item(rnd.Next(0, 3))'select random string from the list
```

it will generate random numbers between 0 and 2 hence it will help you to select random string from the list of strings based on index referenced by the random number

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you generate a random number and then pick up the string at that position in the array

```
string[] arr= {"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm","MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ","1234567890"};
               Random rnd = new Random();
               int cnt = rnd.Next(2);
               string r = arr[cnt];
```