# I have three variables declared as strings, is there a way to randomly choose one?

Tags: vb.net

I have three strings, sUpperCase, sLowerCase and sNumbers. Each have either lower characters, upper characters or numbers. I need to know how to randomly choose one of these strings. I have thought maybe by assigning them a number but I am not sure how do to this without overriding the text inside of them. Maybe even an array but I'm not sure how to do this either. Can anybody help please?

```
Dim sLowerCase As String = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
Dim sUpperCase As String = "MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ"
Dim sNumbers   As String = "1234567890"
```

ANSWER:

```
 Function GeneratePassword() As String
        '
        ' Declare two strings as the characters which the password can be created from
        Dim sLowerCase As String = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
        Dim sUpperCase As String = "MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ"
        Dim sNumbers As String = "1234567890"

        ' Create a new random. 
        ' Random is something which gets a random set of characters from a string. 
        Dim random As New Random

        '
        ' Create sPassword as a new stringbuilder
        ' A stringbuilder is simply a class which builds a string from multiple characters
        Dim sPassword As New StringBuilder

        ' Not random enough
        'For i As Integer = 1 To 4
        '    Dim idxUpper As Integer = random.Next(0, sUpperCase.Length - 1)
        '    sPassword.Append(sUpperCase.Substring(idxUpper, 1))
        '    Dim idxNumber As Integer = random.Next(0, sNumbers.Length - 1)
        '    sPassword.Append(sNumbers.Substring(idxNumber, 1))
        '    Dim idxLower As Integer = random.Next(0, sLowerCase.Length - 1)
        '    sPassword.Append(sLowerCase.Substring(idxLower, 1))
        'Next


        ' Random select Upper, lower or numeric
        ' Check for a max number of this(three if's to check for which one it was, might need or in if)
        ' If yes randomly select another one
        ' If no get random char from that type
        ' Add to password
        ' Is the password complete?
        ' If yes return password, if not repeat

        Dim iCountUpper As Integer = 0
        Dim iCountLower As Integer = 0
        Dim iCountNumber As Integer = 0

        Do Until sPassword.Length = 10
            'Needed help for this bit
            Dim x = New Random(Now.GetHashCode)
            Dim y = {"sLowerCase", "sUpperCase", "sNumbers"}
            Dim z = y(x.Next(0, y.Length))

            If z.Contains("sLowerCase") And iCountUpper < 4 Then

                Dim idxUpper As Integer = random.Next(0, sUpperCase.Length - 1)
                sPassword.Append(sUpperCase.Substring(idxUpper, 1))
                iCountUpper = iCountUpper + 1

            ElseIf z.Contains("sUpperCase") And iCountLower < 4 Then
                Dim idxLower As Integer = random.Next(0, sLowerCase.Length - 1)
                sPassword.Append(sLowerCase.Substring(idxLower, 1))
                iCountLower = iCountLower + 1

            ElseIf z.Contains("sNumbers") And iCountNumber < 2 Then
                Dim idxNumber As Integer = random.Next(0, sNumbers.Length - 1)
                sPassword.Append(sNumbers.Substring(idxNumber, 1))
                iCountNumber = iCountNumber + 1
            Else

            End If
        Loop

        '
        ' Return the password as a string
        Return sPassword.ToString

    End Function
```

Comment: This is a **re-post** of: [How can I randomly select one of three strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065960/how-can-i-randomly-select-one-of-three-strings)

Comment: It is, sorry I am at home using my home account. However your remark on the other post was not well received. I had done research, I knew I have to use an array/list or some other way and I will delete it now as I have figured out my answer using help from the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim sLowerCase As String = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
Dim sUpperCase As String = "MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ"
Dim sNumbers As String = "1234567890"

Dim x = New Random(Now.GetHashCode)
Dim y = {sLowerCase, sUpperCase, sNumbers}
Dim z = y(x.Next(0, y.Length))
Debug.Print(z)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this returns the actual physical string. What I meant was to return the actual variable name, such as sLowerCase. How would I do that?

Comment: Why do you need the variable name when you can use the value?

Comment: Once I have the the variable name I will be getting a random character from the string and inserting it into a password.

Comment: @TheFool - Again I ask then, why does that require the variable name?

Comment: This is why, look at the question, i will edit it to show you what I have done. I have managed to get it working

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim strings = {"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm", "MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ", "1234567890"}

Dim selected As String
Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
selected = strings(Generator.Next(0, strings.GetUpperBound(0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with your strings:

```
Dim array As String() = New String() {sLowerCase, sUpperCase, sNumbers}
```

Use Random class to generate random number between 0 and the array lenght:

```
Dim random As Random = New Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks)
Dim randomChoose As String = array(random.Next(0, array.Length - 1))
```

Select a random char:

```
Dim ch As Char = randomChoose(random.Next(0, randomChoose.Length - 1))
```